# How to control the shape of ListPlot3D

Tags: plotting

### Problem

I have an array defined as `arr1 = {{0, 0, 0}, {0.6, 0, 0}, {0, 0.4, 0}, {0.6, 0.4, 0}, {1, 0.4, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0.6, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}}`.

I'd like plot somethig like this:

[image]

However, with `plt1 = ListPlot3D[arr1, PlotStyle -> {Opacity[0.5]}, Mesh -> None, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]`,I just got this:

[image]

### My Question

I want to know how I can get a plot with a **square corner** ?

Comment: `RegionFunction` should be useful for cutting off unwanted sections.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@ J.M. I work out my problem with:

```
plt1 = ListPlot3D[arr1, RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, ¬ (x >= 0.6 ∧ y <= 0.4)], PlotStyle -> {Opacity[0.5]}, Mesh -> None, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]
```

Thanks.

[image: the plot]

Comment: Nicely done. :)